# Allow HTTPS only for specific domains with pound

Tags: ssl, https, pound

quick question here:

I have trafic from several domains routed to a Pound Reverse Proxy.

I have a valid certificate for one of these domain that I want accessible over HTTPS (this part I managed to configure without problem)

However I don't want my other domains to be accessible through HTTPS. Is this something I can configure in Pound ? Or should I be doing this somwehere else ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If all the domains share the same IP address then all you can achieve is to cause a browser error due to an invalid certificate when the user tries to access the site with https. If you don't like this you need different IPs for the domains you want to use with HTTPS and for the HTTP-only domains.